# Find Networkx path by a sequence of nodes

Tags: python, networkx

I want to find all the path that starts from a sequence of nodes, the network looks like this:

```
DG = nx.DiGraph()
attrs = {(1, 2), (2,3), (2,4), (4,5), (5, 6), (3,6), (6,7)}
DG.add_edges_from(attrs)
```

What I expect is a list of all path that starts from (1,2,3) and a list (1,2,4):
 `all_path =  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 6], [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]] , [[1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 4, 5]]`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason that the path [1,2,3,4,5,6] wouldn't "count" here?

Comment: Just there is no edge between 3 and 4. so the path doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, I meant [1,2,4,5,6]

Comment: sorry, [1,2,4,5,6] and other possible path counts. I didn't add other path from (1,2,3) and (1,2,4) in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some reading between the lines that you've left for us. For example, are you specifically looking for paths that end in node 7 in this case, or are you just looking for any path that has nowhere else to go (i.e. ends in a node of outdegree zero)? If the path contains a cycle, do we include paths that go around the cycle before ending?

My guess is that what you're really interested in is the set of all simple paths from a given node that end in a node with outdegree zero. With that in mind, here's some code you might find useful.

```
start = 1
ends = [n for n in DG.nodes if DG.out_degree[n] == 0]
paths = [p for e in ends 
         for p in nx.all_simple_paths(DG, source = start, target = e)]
print(paths)
```

Output: `[[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]]`

---

If you want paths that start from 1 and end in any other node, you could do the following.

```
start = 1
paths = [p for e in DG.nodes
         for p in nx.all_simple_paths(DG, source = start, target = e)]
print(paths)
```

Output: `[[1, 2], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 6], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 6, 7], [1, 2, 4, 5]]`.

If you like, you can take this output and filter down to the paths that start with any 3 nodes. For example,

```
print([p for p in paths if p[:3] == [1,2,3]])
print([p for p in paths if p[:3] == [1,2,4]])
```

results in the outputs `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 6], [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]]` and `[[1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 4, 5]]`.

Alternatively, sorting `paths` naturally organizes the paths according to their first nodes. In particular, `sorted(paths)` is the list

```
[[1, 2],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 6],
 [1, 2, 3, 6, 7],
 [1, 2, 4],
 [1, 2, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 4, 5, 6],
 [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

which you could split into two pieces.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. What I am looking for is all the path that starts from three specific nodes to 7.  In your second response, is there anyway to make two lists of list that is [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 6], [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]] and [[1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7],  [1, 2, 4, 5]]

Comment: If you're interested in paths "to 7", then why do you want the elements of the list that don't end in 7, and what is special about the node 7?

Comment: Is there anyway to print all the path that starts from three specific nodes ? (to 7 that is the terminal node)

Comment: See my edit....

Comment: Thanks filtering the path works even if I expand the network :)